# Java: Using the Do-while loop with Scanner Input as a String type: Making a program that calculates simple math and have it repeat if you type yes

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner, do-while

[This is the image of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z064d.png)

I am a little confused how to implement nextLine() in my code. I am looking at my teachers code and I wanted to use a string instead of a char? Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: @Ankit that does not compile.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the lines in the code you linked to do not compile.

For example, `myObj.nextLine();` returns a String, and in java, String and char is not interchangible; the line `isRepeat = someStringExpr;` does not compile.

Separately, don't mix `nextLine` and `nextAnythingElse`, it doesn't work the way you intend. If you want to read entire lines, use `.useDelimiter("\r?\n");` to change the scanner from 'read things separated by spaces' to 'read things separated by newlines'. Then, you can just use `next()` to get an entire line, as a string.

Once you've 'fixed' `isRepeat` to be a `String`, note that in java, strings are delimited by double quotes, so it's `"Yes"`, not 'Yes', and finally, you use `.equals()` to compare strings, not `==` which won't work: `while (isRepeat.equals("Yes"));` is what you're looking for.

Note that in the original code, `.next()` is used (not nextLine - you don't want nextLine).